# Hive table creation with adl credentials configurable

Tags: azure, hive, azure-data-lake

Team,

In hive create table I need to load adl file,When I googled I found Provider Type, Client Id,Client Credential need to be configured in core-site.xml. My requirement is that we need to configure these credential dynamically while creating a hive table. The same is done for while loading to s3 file into hive table.

```
create table employee(
    id int,
    name string
) location 's3a://<access_key>:<secret_key>@<my-bucket>/<s3_path>'
```

Similarly, same can be achieved for creating hive table on adl file path?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. no, for reason (2)
2. that feature of secrets-in-URI has gone from S3A because it ended causing your critical AWS secrets to be logged everywhere: your application logs, error messages in exceptions, etc.

you'll need to come up with another solution I'm afraid.